# Calling controller from layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am new to MVC.

I have the following in my layout page:

```
<div id="RunValidation">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("RunValidation", "Home"))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chkFindDuplicates" value="chkFindDuplicates">Find Cards
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chkFindDuplicates" value="chkFindDuplicates">Find Duplicates
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chkFindSuspectVoucherAllocation" value="chkFindSuspectVoucherAllocation">Find Suspect Voucher Allocataion
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="SubmitValidation" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
```

I have the following Action in my HomeController:

```
public ActionResult RunValidaton()
    {
        //determine which validations checks to run
        int x = 0;


        //call into middle tier to execute the validation

        return View();

    }
```

My route config is as follows:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

When I click the submit button on my html form I'm hoping to hit a breakpoint on the int x = 0; line in the controller, but I get a 404 error.

From Fiddler I can see the following in the Post header:

```
POST /Home/RunValidation HTTP/1.1
```

I can't understand why the request is not being routed to the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Please Change your Action method name. See below code

```
<div id="RunValidation">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Jeet", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chkFindDuplicates" value="chkFindDuplicates">Find Cards
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chkFindDuplicates" value="chkFindDuplicates">Find Duplicates
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chkFindSuspectVoucherAllocation" value="chkFindSuspectVoucherAllocation">Find Suspect Voucher Allocataion
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="SubmitValidation" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div> 

    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Jeet()
        {

            //determine which validations checks to run
            int x = 0;


            //call into middle tier to execute the validation

            return View();

        }


 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultRunValidation",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Jeet", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: When I tried this change and started the website I got HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Try to create Action with http method anotation and action parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RunValidaton(FormCollection form) //your model here would be better.
    {
        //determine which validations checks to run
        int x = 0;


        //call into middle tier to execute the validation

        return View();

    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this had no impact